# Observer\DOMDocument' not found when use new DOMDocument() in Obeserver

Tags: magento-2.1

I am calling api in the Obeserver file. After this load xml data of response i am using

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($response);
```

But i am getting Fatal Error: Class 'PackageName\ModuleName\Observer\DOMDocument' not found in

Please provide me some solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found solution

We can use as following:

```
use Magento\Framework\DomDocument\DomDocumentFactory;

public function __construct(
 DomDocumentFactory $domFactory
) {

    $this->domFactory = $domFactory;

}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $doc = $this->domFactory->create();
    $doc->loadXML($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use it including it like this:

`````
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Controller\Checkout;

use \DOMDocument;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class MyClass ...

````
`````